# How fast will hydrazine boil out of a tube into a vacuum?

Tags: thermodynamics, sublimation

[For context I'm talking about ISEE-3](http://spacecollege.org/isee3/isee-3-post-lunar-flyby-status-and-modification-of-mission-goals.html) and how long it would take to dump the now useless and hazardous fuel it still carries.

Given a heated tank of hydrazine (somewhere near $0~^\circ\mathrm{C}$) connected by way of [a long slender unheated tube](http://images.spaceref.com/news/spacecollege/isee3/propulsion.l.jpg) to a infinite high vacuum, how fast will the tank vent to ~zero pressure?

My guess is that rather quickly, the boiling action will produce a plug of frozen hydrazine in the tube. Once that happens, the sublimation on the outer face will cause condensation and/or solidification on the other face and the plug will walk back towards the tank until it either reaches it or the solid portion of the plug get to thin in which case it will burst and vent like in the beginning and start over.

The question is, how fast will this happen?

---

Edit: on further inspection, it looks like the "tube" may be heated after all.